# When is it ok to throw a ServletException from a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have been throwing `ServletException`s in the past, when something/anything goes wrong in a Servlet, mostly just wrapping the exception in `ServletException`.

Now I am thinking it is actually better to not throw a `ServletException` but to respond with `response.sendError(sc)` and use the correct HTTP status codes.

If I can't send an error using `reponse.sendError`, (`IOException`), I wrap the `IOException` in a `ServletException`.

Is the above a better way to respond?
When is it OK to just throw a `ServletException`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have just come to the opposite conclusion to @alamar. My situation is writing a REST-style servlet to be called by code in an Oracle database, not by humans.

I want to return the HTTP code *400 Bad Request* to the caller when the request information is invalid or missing. Throwing a `ServletException` causes the container to return *500 Internal Server Error*, which states there is something wrong with the server, not with the request.

Here is the solution I adopted.

1. Create a simple exception class `RequestException` that extends `Exception`.
2. Check the validity of the request with method(s) that throw `new RequestException(message)`.
3. Catch `RequestException` in the servlet’s `doPost` method and call `HttpServletResponse.sendError()` like this:

   ```
   try {
       validateRequest(request);
       // Do stuff with a valid request.
   } catch (RequestException e) {
       response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

The message is returned to the caller as it would be with a `ServletException`.

Comment: What HTTP error does `IOException` cause the container to return?

Comment: @ADTC A quick experiment shows that Tomcat 7 throws _500 Internal Server Error_ for an `IOException`, as it does for `ServletException`. I don’t know if this behaviour is by specification or by convention.

Answer (score 10):

It is better to throw a `ServletException`.

You can later actually catch this exception with error-page directive in your `web.xml`, and make appropriate actions: display a fancy error page to user, send the exception along with the stack trace to developers, write it to logs and so on.

If you just use `sendError()`, you can't do that, to various extents.

Comment: I actually forgot about that, in the past I did do the same thing in web sites. At the moment I am using a servlet to create a simple XML web service, so in that context there is no page to show. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @alamar, will you elaborate on your approach?  Perhaps post some code?  I'm especially curious with the bit that routes the stacktrace and writes to the log.